# Incorrect rate limit values when using app authentication

Tags: php, podio

Can anyone shed some insight as to why I would be seeing a different rate_limit_remaining after my Podio::filter call.

My app credentials are stored in a multidimensional area that I increment the index once Ive gotten close to the rate limit. I seem to be grabbing the wrong credentials

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Podio has two tiers of rate limits: normal, and rate limited calls. `PodioItem::filter` is a rate limited call, which has a lower rate limit.

You can get around this by creating a saved view with your filter parameters, and using `PodioItem::filter_by_view` instead. `PodioItem::filter_by_view` uses your normal rate limit instead of the intensive one.

See more: https://developers.podio.com/index/limits

Also relevant is Andreas' response: https://help.podio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202750276-Discrepancy-in-rate-limit-reporting-

I also recall that certain API calls are restricted when using the app authentication flow, so that may be why the rate limit is switching over.